# PHP TCPDF Create Multiple PDFS

Tags: php, tcpdf

I've created a report and exported it to PDF using TCPDF.
I want to send different parts of the report to different mail adresses, therefor I have to create multiple PDFS in one proccess.
Is it possible doing it using TCPDF? If it is , how can I practically do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCPDF is designed for creating single PDFs.

A possible way to do it practically would be to create multiple TCPDF objects, and methods for adding a report piece to a PDF, and using code to add the report to the pdf.

```
$requested = array('marketing', 'sales', 'customer service');
$pdfs = array();
foreach ($requested as $type) {
    $pdfs[$type] = createPdfObject();
}

$reportPiece = createGraphForSalesAndMarketing();
addReportPiece($pdfs['marketing'], $reportPiece);
addReportPiece($pdfs['sales'], $reportPiece);
```

Emailing each pdf to a different email address as an attachment would be better answered by just searching for existing answers to the many ways of doing it.

Comment: i am getting this issue...Catchable fatal error: Object of class TCPDF could not be converted to string

Comment: There are a number of reasons you could be getting an error about converting an object to a string.  It may be better to open that issue as a new question.   Quickest answer, based on vague information would be 'have you tried using the output function of TCPDF?'  http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1